# Is there a way in software to check what the controller on my SSD is?

Tags: ssd

I'm considering being *bad* and buying an off brand, chinese SSD that's insanely cheap, has no reviews and possibly one of those dram-less controllers.

I'd like to science the *heck* out of it. I'd like to see if it meets the specifications listed and check if anyone else uses these controller. I'm not averse to removing the casing, but I'd rather *avoid* it.

However there's no data sheet for these things and no intrepid folk taking them apart.

So.. for the sake of science, is there any way to do this? I'll be running tests in windows, for consistancy's sake (since that's what I'll be running), so I'd prefer a windows specific way to do it. If the only way to do it is in linux, I'm cool with that too.

Comment: all tools that I know have a database which they build up on datasheets and display the data (SSD-Z, AIDA64)